# Ошибка ресурсов приложения в android studio

Tags: android, java, android-studio

В проекте Android Studio вдруг выделилась красным цветом буква R.

```
  setContentView(R.layout.la_t);
```

Нашел в Сети, что это может означать ошибку ресурсов.
Но что с этим делать? Как исправить?
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Меня обычно спасало исправление ошибок в файле с ресурсами и запуск чистки проекта

Comment: для начала можно попробовать сделать ребилд (Build-Rebuild Project). Если не поможет - проверьте внимательно XML ресурсы, которые вы в последнее время меняли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно помогает
Tools -> Android -> Sync Project witch Gradle Files , либо 
Build -> Clean Project , Rebuild Project

Comment: можно просто Build -> Rebuild Project. Rebuild подразумевает Clean.

Answer (score 4):

Да, такое бывает время от времени. Пугаться этого особо не стоит - с вашим проектом все в порядке, если вы его, конечно же, не импортировали.

Причины тут разные могут быть: синхронизируйте заново конфиг Gradle (сборщик вашего Android-проекта), убедитесь, что пути до Android SDK не изменились. А если залезете в конфиг проекта, что в контекстном меню, то, скорее всего увидите источник ошибки.

Полазьте по Project Structure..., перезапустите ADB, в конце концов. Это, в общем-то, может быть и баг в еще не до конца стабильной Android Studio.

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый ответ. Буду пробовать.

Comment: А где это искать "синхронизируйте заново конфиг Gradle"?

Comment: Все нашел, исправил, благодарю!

Comment: А, что именно исправил и где. Подскажи, пожалуйста, у меня похожая проблема((((

Comment: В AndroidStudio идем в 
File -> Settings -> Gradle-> Use default gradle wrapper (галка) -> Apply
Может я еще какую-то галку включил, не помню, но все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте перезайти в проект, до этого сохранив все.
Если не поможет, перейдите во вкладку Build - Clean Project/ Rebuild Project.