# IDEA не видит R класс

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Совершенно нубский вопрос, но так ничгео и не нагуглил:
Создаю новый андроид проект в IDEA c активностью. Но идеа не видит R класс! (точнее видит через раз). 
Как его заимпортить или что другое нужно сделать (import android.R не помогает - тогда main_layout выделяет красным) ?

IDEA выдает ошибку gradle "aidl is missing".

код **build.gradle**:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devcolibri.myapplication6.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Скрин во вложении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Android sdk все нужные компоненты загружены?

Comment: Загружены все extras и tools, а также API 22 и API 19

Comment: Выложите код вашего build.gradle, возможно несоответствие версий.

Comment: причем здесь компоненты SDK , несоответствия версий и автогенерируемый класс ссылок на ресурсы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414221/177345 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427075/177345

Comment: код добавил в тело вопроса.

Comment: Clean/Rebuild не работает - ту же ошибку выдает. Invalidate caches тоже не помогает.

Кажется мне что у меня gradle как то криво стоит.
Можно подробнее про его установку? Я его просто разархивировал в папку на диск. В переменных среды создал новую переменную GRADLE_HOME. Но в идее эту переменную нигде не указывал. И вообще содержание окна при создании проекта намекает, что gradle  уже включен в ultimate сборку idea. Где его там найти?

(Все что спрашиваю здесь безуспешно гуглил( )

Comment: Попробовал в настройках выбрать use local gradle distribution, но все равно та же ошибка

Comment: просто в настройках gradle выберите: " Use default gradle wrapper" , оно само все скачает, установит куда надо и будет использовать, возможно придется подождать. Затем нужно синхронизировать файлы грэдла с проектом. К сожалению, в IDEA (в отличии от Android Studio) нет в меню пункта "Sync project with gradle files" , его надо добыть из глубин IDE -  поэтому делаете, что написано [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24956120)

Comment: Еще для синхронизации конфигов грэдла с проектом (Help IDEA предлагает именно [такой способ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html) ) можно использовать вкладку `Gradle` слева ( или View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle ) , там нажать на значок "Refresh all gradle project" ( крайний левый, в форме двух синих стрелочек по кругу ( обычно так выглядит "обновить" )

Comment: пробовал и через sync и через View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle. Обновляет но все равно aidl is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте строку в build.gradle `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"` на `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` и будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Заработало!

Скажите, а почему так вышло что версия не та была прописана?

Comment: @АлександрДворцов да, версия 23.0.0 rc1 совсем новая и вызавает конфликт. В будуще Google поправят.