# Как установить в андроид студио compileDebugAid

Tags: android, android-studio

В Android Studio не могу работать. Приложение не запускается, а выдает ошибку:

> Error: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> aidl is missing

А обновить программу не могу. Что делать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427315/177345 ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Правой кнопкой нажмите на `app folder` и выберите `Open Modular Settings`.
   Должна появиться таблица как на скриншоте.
2. В строке `Build tools version` выберите 22.0.1 вместо 23.0.0.rc1
3. Нажмите `OK`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]